# Split number and string from the value using java script or regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

I have a value "4.66lb"

and i want to separate "4.66" and "lb" using regex.

I tried the below code, but that separates only number "4,66"!! but i want both the values 4.66 and lb.

```
var text = "4.66lb";
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
alert(text.match(/(\d+)/g));
```

Comment: Have you tried appending `([a-z]+)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
var res = text.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\D+)/);
```

`res[1]` contains `4.66`
`res[2]` contains `lb`

In order to match also `4/5lb`, you could use:

```
var res = text.match(/(\d+(?:[.\/]\d+)?)(\D+)/);
```

Comment: Short and sweet, +1. :)

Comment: Hey, i have one more scenario where the number can be 4/5lb, so in this case i need to split 4/5 and lb....so what would be the regex for this?

Comment: @user3770003: replace the dot by a slash: `/(\d+(?:\/\d+)?)(\D+)/`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a character class also,

```
> var res = text.match(/([0-9\.]+)(\w+)/);
undefined
> res[1]
'4.66'
> res[2]
'lb'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Let me explain with an example

```
var str = ' 1 ab 2 bc 4 dd';   //sample string

str.split(/\s+\d+\s+/)
result_1 = ["", "ab", "bc", "dd"]  //regex not enclosed in parenthesis () will split string on the basis of match expression

str.split(/(\s+\d+\s+)/)        //regex enclosed in parenthesis () along with above results, it also finds all matching strings
result_2 = ["", " 1 ", "ab", " 2 ", "bc", " 4 ", "dd"] 

//here we received two type of results: result_1 (split of string based on regex) and those matching the regex itself

//Yours case is the second one
//enclose the desired regex in parenthesis
solution : str.split(/(\d+\.*\d+[^\D])/)
```